# Dialogflow - Google Assistant: Show suggestions with icon + text

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm showing a list of suggestions in my Google Assistant agent. I'm using WebhookClient object (agent), to handle the responses. My code looks like:

```
function showSuggestions(){
    agent.add(new Suggestion(`Suggestion 1`));
    agent.add(new Suggestion(`Suggestion 2`));
    agent.add(new Suggestion(`Suggestion 3`));
}
```

I'm wishing to add a small icon in the left of the text in the *suggestions buttons*. I'm expecting kind of:

```
function showSuggestions(){
    agent.add(new Suggestion(<icon1> + `Suggestion 1`));
    agent.add(new Suggestion(<icon2> + `Suggestion 2`));
    agent.add(new Suggestion(<icon3> + `Suggestion 3`));
}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now it is not possible to attach an icon to your text in a suggestion. The Suggestion object only accepts string as a parameter ([reference](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_response.suggestions.html#constructor)). 
Nonetheless, you can use emojis without a problem, like

```
agent.add(new Suggestion(' Suggestion 1'));
```

There are also some nodejs packages for emojis that might be useful to you:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-emoji

https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-regex

Comment: The suggestion text needs to be the same as the user input expected. So with emoji's you might have intent matching issues.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry,at the moment the Assistant only supports text type Suggestions, you can check its valid property here => [Suggestion Documentation](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_response.suggestions.html#constructor)